# jQuery custom validation method never gets called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML and JavaScript similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Validation Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <input id="TotalHours" type="text" value="24"/> is the total number of hours!
        <input id="day" class="input" type="text"/> is the number of hours of daylight!
        <input id="night" class="input" type="text"/> is the number of hours of darkness!
        <script>
            validationRules = {
                TotalHours: {
                    TotalHoursMatch: true
                }
            };
            $.validator.addMethod("TotalHoursMatch", function(value, element) {
                // find total hours
                var reportedTotalHours = parseFloat($("#TotalHours").text());

                var totalHours = 0;
                $('input.input').each(function(i, sel) {
                    var hours = $(sel).find(":selected").text();
                    var f = parseFloat(hours);
                    if (f != 0 && !Number.isNaN(f))
                        totalHours += f;
                });

                // validate that hours are within a quarter hour of each other
                var difference = Math.abs(totalHours - reportedTotalHours);
                return difference < 0.25;
            }, "Total of hours for daylight and darkness must match total hours in a day.");

            function doSubmit()
            {
                $('form').validate({rules: validationRules});
                if (!$('form').valid())
                    alert('bad!');
                else
                    alert('ok');
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="doSubmit();">submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for some reason when I go to validate the form, the custom validation method never gets called, even though I think I set it up properly. Thus "ok" is always displayed; the validation never fails because the method which does the validation is not called. Why is this? What am I missing here to hook up the validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I needed to set a `name="TotalHours"` on the first input field; the `id` is not sufficient.